# Should we have a [calculator] tag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, tags

Example questions:

> [Simple calculator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63801/simple-calculator)
>   [Java Calculator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/41019/java-calculator)
>   [Console calculator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/13311/console-calculator)
>   [Ruby Kata Gem: Calculator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/33818/ruby-kata-gem-calculator)
>   [Calculator - C++ operator-overloading](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79185/calculator-c-operator-overloading)
>   [Small Python calculator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/46698/small-python-calculator)
>   [Calculator using class templates](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79768/calculator-using-class-templates)
>   [Shortening calculator project code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/40526/shortening-calculator-project-code)
>   [Simple Java calculator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/40615/simple-java-calculator)
>   [String calculator kata](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/18995/string-calculator-kata)
>   [String calculator in F#](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/10382/string-calculator-in-f)
>   [Basic android calculator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/13005/basic-android-calculator)
>   [Basic calculator in jQuery](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/38947/basic-calculator-in-jquery)
>   [Calculator Android App](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/40807/calculator-android-app)
>   [Refactoring a String Calculator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/43057/refactoring-a-string-calculator)
>   [Calculator with simple input](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/78031/calculator-with-simple-input)
>   [Basic C# calculator (+,-,*,/) - V2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/67576/basic-c-calculator-v2)
>   [Basic C# calculator (+,-,*,/)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/67054/basic-c-calculator)

Much like [hangman](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hangman), [tic-tac-toe](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tic-tac-toe), or [number-guessing-game](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-guessing-game), calculators are one of the first things one may be asked to program in order to learn a language. I think it would be helpful to have a tag for the many calculators.

So, how about [calculator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculator)?

Comment: Yes, definitely. The question should be: what should be the defining characteristics of a calculator?

Comment: It does arithmetic on input numbers. ... with that being the main goal.

Comment: I guess your real question is; is a tax calculator worthy of the calculator tag? That I don't know just yet.

Comment: We didn't have a tag for this already...? Strange!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, go ahead and create it. The Stack Overflow tag has the description:

> This tag is for questions about calculators, or calculator programming.

I would recommend reusing the excerpt, like:

> This tag is for questions about calculators.

but adding the wiki text:

> Calculator questions have the basic concept that it supports the input of a sequence of values and operators, and the program computes the result. The format used for the input, whether it is Postfix (also called RPN - Reverse Polish Notation) like `3 4 +` or Infix like `3 + 4` should be clarified in the question

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix_notation
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation

Comment: Thanks for wiki texts

Comment: Evaluating postfix and infix expressions would be better covered under [tag:math-expression-eval]. We might want a narrower definition of [tag:calculator].

Comment: Why not include prefix notation for 100% coverage? This pedantry in the tag might preempt  pedantry in the comments.